# how do I figure out the right order to drop tables in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-schema

I've got a set of tables that I need to drop in an Sqlite file. They have foreign key constraints. How do I figure out the right order to drop the tables? Or is there a "drop a list of tables" command that will figure that out for me? And what do I search for on the web to get help on this question as adding "order" to any web search related to SQL returns info about the ORDER keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a table has a foreign key in it, the constraint will prevent you from dropping the table that owns the foreign key.  A "foreign key" is simply the primary key of another table, thus it is "foreign" to you. So you need to drop the tables with foreign keys first -- then you can drop those other tables.  Dropping a table drops its constraints as well.

For brute forcing things you should be able to disable the constraints using:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
```

Comment: Well, I can't just drop all tables with foreign keys in an arbitrary order; some of those contain the primary key that is foreign in other tables.

Comment: Try disabling the constraints, as indicated in my amended answer.